# I keep getting a "grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous" error

Tags: python, websocket, telemetry

wanting to write a python script that listens to websocket using pygNMi and collect data data, however I keep getting a "grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous" error. this is the code below:

## Modules

```
from pygnmi.client import gNMIclient, telemetryParser
from inventory import hosts
import pprint

# Body
for host_entry in hosts:
    if host_entry["nos"] == "Ciena": # network operating system
        print(host_entry)
        subscribe = {
            'subscription': [
                {
                    'path': '', # path   
                    'mode': 'sample', #collects the full data 
                    'sample_interval': 10000000000
                }
            ],

            'mode': 'stream',
            'encoding': 'proto',
            #'target': 'pm'
        }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with gNMIclient(target=(host_entry["ip_address"], host_entry["port"]),
                    username=host_entry["username"], password=host_entry["password"], skip_verify=True, debug=True) as gc:
        telemetry_stream = gc.subscribe(subscribe=subscribe)

     
    for telemetry_entry in telemetry_stream:
        raw_data = telemetryParser(telemetry_entry)
        pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
        pp.pprint(raw_data)
```

this is the error message i'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\e030734\Desktop\python_decoder\main.py", line 30, in <module>
    for telemetry_entry in telemetry_stream:
  File "C:\Users\e030734\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 540, in __next__
    return self._next()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\e030734\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 949, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.CANCELLED
        details = "Channel closed!"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {grpc_message:"Channel closed!", grpc_status:1, created_time:"2024-02-26T02:19:48.7908298+00:00"}"
```

I want it to listen to the channel and recieve data.